# what's the matter with bulk update method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I wrote a bulk update by spring boot jdbcTemplate, the response code is 200, but the mysql recodes haven't updated yet, I don't know the reason, here is my codes:

```
@Override
  @Transactional
  public void updateCustomCategory(List<ItemDto> itemDtoList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemDtoList)) {
      jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("update item_tab set l1_custom_category_id = ? AND l2_custom_category_id = ? where item_id = ?",
              new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                  ps.setLong(1, itemDtoList.get(i).getL1CustomCatId());
                  ps.setLong(2, itemDtoList.get(i).getL2CustomCatId());
                  ps.setLong(3, itemDtoList.get(i).getItemId());
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                  return 500;
                }
              });
    }
  }
```

how should I modify the logic?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question and answer? Your answer is not detailed enough to understand what you want to tell us.

Comment: my bad, just fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue fixed now, add the "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" and index for "itemid"